# Get a phrase from speech recognizer similar to result returned by Google Now

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Im currently building a feature of my app that should allow the user to say a phrase which will then be compared with a phrase said by another user to determine if they are equal.  I am getting back results from the Speech Recognizer Intent as follows.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
 {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
```

When I tried it by saying "Testing 123" I got back an array populated with "Testing 123, Testing one two three, Piscon 123"

Is there a way I can only extract the most accurate phrase from the result such as just "Testing 123" ? When I do a search with Google Now only the most accurate representation of what I said is returned so I'm wondering if this functionality can be achieved.

I tried "How high can you jump" and got this result. Is there a way to somewhat determine the start of the next sentence so I can extract the most positive result?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to get just the most accurate, you'll want to also grab `EXTRA_CONFIDENCE_SCORES`. You'll want to find the highest confidence score and the corresponding String value.From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_RESULTS)

> public static final String EXTRA_RESULTS
>
> Added in API level 3
> An ArrayList of the recognition results when performing ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH. Generally this list should be ordered in descending order of speech recognizer confidence. (See EXTRA_CONFIDENCE_SCORES). Returned in the results; not to be specified in the recognition request. Only present when RESULT_OK is returned in an activity result. In a PendingIntent, the lack of this extra indicates failure.

And confidence scores:

> public static final String EXTRA_CONFIDENCE_SCORES
>
> Added in API level 14
> A float array of confidence scores of the recognition results when performing ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH. The array should be the same size as the ArrayList returned in EXTRA_RESULTS, and should contain values ranging from 0.0 to 1.0, or -1 to represent an unavailable confidence score.
>
> Confidence values close to 1.0 indicate high confidence (the speech recognizer is confident that the recognition result is correct), while values close to 0.0 indicate low confidence.
>
> Returned in the results; not to be specified in the recognition request. This extra is optional and might not be provided. Only present when RESULT_OK is returned in an activity result.